# Can this strange behaviour be explained by Eventual Consistency on the App Engine Datastore?

Tags: database, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, database-replication, acid

I have implemented two server-side HTTP endpoints which 1) stores some data and 2) processes it. Method 1) calls method 2) through [App Engine Tasks](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/taskqueue/overview) since they are time consuming tasks that I do not want the client to wait for. The process is illustrated in the sequence diagram below.

Now from time to time I experience that the processing task (named *processSomething* in the sequence diagram below) can't find the data when attempting to process - illustrated with the yellow `throw WtfException()` below. Can this be explained with the **Eventual Consistency** model [described here](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/overview#Ancestor_Paths)?

The document says *Strong consistency for reads* but *eventual consistency for writes*. I'm not sure what exactly that means related to this case. Any clarification is appreciated.

[image]

**edit:** I realize I'm asking a boolean question here, but I guess I'm looking for an answer backed up with some documentation on what Eventual Consistency is in general and specifically on Google Datastore

**edit 2:** By request here are details on the actual read/write operations:

*The write operation:*

```
entityManager.persist(hand); 
entityManager.close()
```

I'm using JPA for data persistance. Object 'hand' is recieved from client and not previously stored in the db so a new key `Id` will be assigned.

*The read operation*:

```
SELECT p FROM Hand p WHERE p.GameId = :gid AND p.RoundNo = :rno
```

Neither `GameId` nor `RoundNo` is the primary key. GameId is a "foreign key" although the Datastore is oblivious of that by design.

Comment: if you load(id) by key, I think you should get the updated entity. From doc "Because Datastore gets and ancestor queries apply any outstanding modifications before executing, these operations always see a consistent view of all previous successful transactions. This means that a get operation (looking up an updated entity by its key) is guaranteed to see the latest version of that entity."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would help if you showed actual code, showing how you save the entity and how you retrieve it, but assuming that `id` is an actual datastore ID, part of a Key, and that your `load` is a `get` using the id and not a `query` on some other property then eventual-consistency is not your issue.

(The documentation on this is [further down the page you linked](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/overview#Datastore_Writes_and_Data_Visibility).)

Comment: I've updated the question with details on the db interaction code. As you can see, both your assumptions are false, but I guess it then can be deduced that the main answer is **yes** to my question: Eventual Consistency *may* be the problem here. Agree?

Comment: Yes, it is definitely a candidate.